# Add thread loop timer

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, loops, timer

I currently have a small program which checks when loaded if the user has an internet connection or not. If not, then a picture box is displayed otherwise the picturebox is hidden. This works perfectly fine on load, but if the user was to disconnect from the internet after the program has been loaded then nothing happens.

How would I go about adding a timer or a loop into my program?

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Checkthread = New Thread(AddressOf Me.CheckConnection)
    Checkthread.Start()



End Sub


Private Sub CheckConnection()
    If internetConnection() = False Then
        InternetStatus = False

    Else
        InternetStatus = True

    End If
    AccessPicture()

End Sub

Private Sub AccessPicture()
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf AccessPicture))
    Else

        If InternetStatus = False Then
            PicInternet.Show()

        Else
            PicInternet.Hide()

        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Function internetConnection() As Boolean
    Dim req As System.Net.WebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.co.uk/")
    Dim resp As System.Net.WebResponse

    Try
        resp = req.GetResponse()
        resp.close()
        req = Nothing
        Return True

    Catch ex As Exception
        req = Nothing
        Return False
    End Try




End Function
```

Comment: One way, use the [`Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) class - has an example to get you started on there too.

Comment: Note you have a potential memory leak because you are not disposing of your response object. This could have an impact if you do this continually in a timer

Comment: Instead of accessing google, can you access the site that is important for the software? Also, you should call AccessPicture only when there's a need to change the picture visibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make your life much easier by using a library that will help make your timer code very easy to work with. I would suggest using Microsoft's Reactive Framework (NuGet "Rx-WinForms").

Here's your code:

```
Private _subscription As IDisposable

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    _subscription = _
        Observable _
            .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30.0)) _
            .StartWith(-1) _
            .Select(Function(x) internetConnection()) _
            .ObserveOn(Me) _
            .Subscribe(Sub(x)
                           If x Then
                               PicInternet.Show()
                           Else
                               PicInternet.Hide()
                           End If
                       End Sub)
End Sub
```

This sets up an observable that will fire immediately, and then every 30 seconds, to call `internetConnection` and to send its value to the UI thread so that you can show or hide the picture.

Oh, and here's a cleaner version of your `internetConnection` method.

```
Private Function internetConnection() As Boolean
    Dim req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.co.uk/")
    Try
        Using resp = req.GetResponse()
            Return True
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

That's it.

When you're finished and you want to close your form just call `_subscription.Dispose()` first to turn off the observable.

Comment: Thank you, I was firstly having a problem with   Observable _ but I completely forgot to add Imports System.Reactive.Linq solved my problem, cheers.